# Android application has external SD card write permissions but I still cannot modify files

Tags: java, android

I am targeting API 24+ for my Android application so I need to request permissions at runtime. I have the request permissions code as shown below. It does not pull up a dialog that asks permissions to write to external storage. According to both my emulator and my phone, I already have write permissions to external storage. This is confirmed by going into the application settings on my phone where it shows the app with permission to read and write to my SD card. However, when I run the application I cannot delete any files from my SD card. File.canWrite() returns false and File.setWritable(true) also returns false. The permissions for READ and WRITE external storage both exist in my manifest file.

```
String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
requestPermissions(permissions, MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                configureSettings();
                listFilesForFolder(folder);
                checkMatches();
                deleteDuplicates();
                textViewStatus.append("\nCompleted!");
                writeLogFile();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                break;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

When the code above is run, it evaluates the permission as granted and carries out the rest of the operations, but it cannot delete the files.

Comment: Since KitKat SD cards are mounted with READ_ONLY permission. There's a lot of answers regarding that issue.

Comment: do you mean physical SD card?

Comment: Yes, physical external SD card. On version 7.0 and above

Comment: `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not related to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), such as a physical external SD card. You don't have read/write access to arbitrary locations on removable storage. Consider using the Storage Access Framework.